# How to convert EXE to ActiveX?(exe is generated from matlab)

Tags: matlab, activex, exe

I made a gui in Matlab and I have converted it to exe.
I want to embed it in a webpage but I heard that only ActiveX can be used.
Does anyone know how to convert a exe(generated from Matlab GUI) to ActiveX so that it can be embedded in a webpage???
Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes ActiveX part is right, but it's a thing which belongs a decade ago. Also it only works with IE. Other browsers will fail. And to your main question, no you can't.

Comment: If the program is portable to javascript, I can suggest rewrite your matlab code in javascript, and create a gui in html.

Comment: @st.  Thanks, but the Matlab GUI is a quite big one and I think it cannot be rewrite in Javascript?? since it require many functions from Matlab